# Are nested time tags valid in HTML5 (in expressing time period/duration)?

Tags: html, datetime, semantics

I was trying to express a time period with `<time>` tags and I thought of using this:

```
<time datetime="P4Y"><time>2000</time>-<time>2004</time></time>
```

Is this valid and semantically correct? If not, are there any better/simpler ways to express something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-time-element) and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) specs say the same thing: that this does, at least, meet the content model (which is probably what you mean by "valid", insofar as a conformance checker would accept it) of the `time` element (though the (pretty much unmaintained) W3C fork contains a contradiction in its definition, [whatwg/html#426](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/426)).

In short: the `time` element can contain "[Phrasing Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)" if it has a `datetime` attribute, and otherwise it can contain only "[Text](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#text-content)"; the `time` element itself is Phrasing Content. That's definitely the case for what you have above.

As for the longer question whether it is semantically correct (and otherwise conforming, as semantic correctness is a conformance requirement for HTML documents), one must consider the following:

> The time element represents its contents, along with a machine-readable form of those contents in the datetime attribute.

Now, the question here is whether `<time>2000</time>-<time>2004</time>` has the same meaning as `P4Y` (i.e., whether it's contents and the machine-readable datetime attribute differ only in form): I'd say it's quite clear-cut here that there are two different semantics here. In the contents, you're representing the specific time interval from 2000 to 2004; in the attribute, you're representing a generic four year duration. These two are not the same, therefore the outer `time` element is not semantically acceptable.

Comment: "the outer `time` element is not semantically acceptable", but afaik there is also no way of expressing the start of the time period. So, basically it's not possible to express what I want with the current spec, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is from W3C

> The time element represents its contents, along with a
>   machine-readable form of those contents in the datetime attribute. The
>   kind of content is limited to various kinds of dates, times, time-zone
>   offsets, and durations, as described below.
>
> The datetime attribute may be present. If present, its value must be a
>   representation of the element's contents in a machine-readable format.
>
> **A time element that does not have a datetime content attribute must
>   not have any element descendants.**

this is the reference

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element

Comment: That's not relevant part as to whether they can be nested: the relevant part is the "Contexts in which this element can be used" and the "Content model".

Comment: …and you've just found a normative contradiction in the spec. Yay! :\ And it occurs in the far more maintained WHATWG spec, too…

Comment: But yes, per what it says in the "Content model" and the "categories" the element falls into, it can only contain "phrasing content" elements as children, and hence not "any".

Comment: I have slightly update the answer.  so ther'arent my consideration.. now there si only what w3c say... Anyone can  think like prefer..